# Random number between two ranges

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to generate a random number between two ranges in Objective-C.
For example between `[-50;-30]` and `[30,50]`.

I achieved to do it between `[-50,50]` but I need to eliminate all the values between `[-30,30]`.

```
int rads = -50 + arc4random() % (50 - (-50));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you stick it in a while loop? `while (rads > -30 || rads < 30) rads = ...`

Comment: what about solving it two randoms, one between -30, and -50 and one between 30 and 50

Comment: There are 40 possible values, so just get a random between 0 and 40 and if random < 20 do - 50, if it's not do + 10.

Comment: @Astrogat perfect,thanks - I posted the answer.

Comment: Maybe with between a random between 0 and 20, where you add +30, and randomly multiply by -1 or 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on the previous answer (which has been removed):

1. use `arc4random_uniform`
2. use correct upper bounds and correct arithmetics

Regarding 1: `arc4random_uniform(50)` will yield a number between 0 and 49 inclusive. It will yield that value with a correct unfirom distribution. Using only `arc4random % something` introduces modulo bias.

Regarding 2: You are trying **not** to retrieve **40 values but 42** since you want to be able to retrieve the upper a nd the lower bound values as well. If we simplify the bounds we can see the error better, assume `[-5;-3]` and `[3;5]`: you want the numbers `-5,-4,-3,3,4,5` six values, not 4.

**Solution:**

```
int rads = arc4random_uniform(42) - 20; // values between -20 and 21 inclusive, 42 different numbers
if (rads <= 0) { // subtract from the lower 21 values [-20;0]
    rads = rads - 30; // [-50;-30]
} else { // add to the upper 21 values [1;21]
    rads = rads + 29; // [30;50]
}
```

**More general** for symmetric upper and lower bounds

```
int lower = 30;
int upper = 50;
int diff = upper - lower;
int rads = arc4random_uniform((diff + 1) * 2) - diff; // values between -diff and (diff+1) inclusive, ((diff+1)*2) different numbers
if (rads <= 0) { // subtract from the lower (diff+1) values [-diff;0]
    rads = rads - lower; // [-upper;-lower]
} else { // add to the upper 21 values [1;diff+1]
    rads = rads + lower - 1; // [lower;upper]
}
```

**Note** that you can simplfy the code a bit by moving the conditional substraction up to the initial `rads` calculation and changing the later addition and the condition for adding. BUT that would make the code a bit less readable and intutive.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try would be choosing randomly either 1 or -1. Then multiplying that by another random number between 30-50 would work.

Comment: That is not a solution! Provide some code, if you have question, write a comment, if you dont have the reputation, try to give proper answerses until then

Comment: It proposes a procedure that solves the problem, @luk2302. Code is not a requirement for an answer, though it is often better.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I sort of agree - but it is still very low quality since the proposed answer will not be even close to what OP wants, it will create a strangle distributed random variable between -50 and +50. I may should have put that argument in the first comment already...

Comment: From my reading of the question, OP wants a number from the union of the ranges [-50, -30], [30, 50], @luk2302. Implementing this answer will produce that.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, multiplying a random value between -1 and 1, eg. (-0.25) with a random variable between 30 and 50, eg. 35 will yield eg. -7.5 -> not in the proposed range.

Comment: @luk2302: I see, my edit unfortunately made this less clear than the original. My fault. The suggestion is to choose _one of_ 1 or -1, not to choose a number in that range.

Comment: @JoshCaswell aaaah, yes. I see what you were / are trying to say.

Comment: @cleed were you able to follow our discussion? is that what you were trying to say? If that is the case, might you consider crafting a code snippet for explanation? Some code would have certainly made this discussion redundant

Comment: @luk2302 No. I stumbled upon this post and had an idea, ended up discovering the comment feature